# How do I do Data Binding for an AvaloniaEdit.TextEditor control in WPF?

Tags: wpf, data-binding, wpf-controls, avaloniaui, avalonia

I have a WFP application that uses the Avalonia control library and I am trying to use the AvaloniaEdit.TextEditor control.

Here is the AXAML definition of the control:

```xml
<Window 
    xmlns:AvaloniaEdit="clr-namespace:AvaloniaEdit;assembly=AvaloniaEdit">
    <AvaloniaEdit:TextEditor Grid.Row="3"
       Grid.Column="2"
       Name="SampleEditor"
       Text="{Binding SampleTextSource, Mode=TwoWay}"
       FontFamily="Cascadia Code,Consolas,Menlo,Monospace"
       HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
       VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"/>
```

Here is the (Model)data source I'm trying to bind to:

```cs
[Reactive] public string? SampleTextSource { get; set; }
```

**Here is the compile time error message I'm getting:**

> Error XAMLIL  Unable to find suitable setter or adder for property Text
> of  type AvaloniaEdit:AvaloniaEdit.TextEditor for argument
> Avalonia.Markup:Avalonia.Data.Binding, available setter parameter
> lists are:

For standard WPF TextBoxes, the following binding works fine:

```xml
<TextBox Text="{Binding SampleTextSource, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

This does not work for the AvaloniaEdit.TextEditor.

I've browsed around and did find any examples of how to implement this. How do I implement 2 way binding for my Avalonia TextEditor?

To the editors:
I'm talking about the AvaloniaUI (cross platform) TextEditor control and NOT the AvalonEdit (WPF windows only) TextEditor control.

Comment: Please leave this question open. The AvalonUI and AvaloniaUI Frameworks are different.  The DependencyProperty solution for AvalonUI will not work for the AvaloniaUI TextEditor as it does not exist in AvaloniaUI. The AvalonEdit solution does not work. I need one specific to AvaloniaUI.